# Appending additional SQL tigger to existing trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have the following SQL update trigger that works properly:

```
BEGIN
DECLARE myID INT;

SELECT user_id INTO myID FROM writer WHERE writer_id = NEW.writer_id;

IF (NEW.status_id = 2)  THEN
    INSERT INTO activity (
        user_id,
        work_id,
        activity,
        date_created
    ) VALUES (
        myID,
        NEW.work_id,
        'confirmed',
        now()
    );
ELSE
    INSERT INTO activity (
        user_id,
        work_id,
        activity,
        date_created
    ) VALUES (
        myID,
        NEW.work_id,
        'modified',
        now()
    );

END IF;
END
```

I need to add an additional trigger as the following:

```
CREATE TRIGGER updateWorkStatus AFTER UPDATE ON writer_split
FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    UPDATE work a
      JOIN writer_split b
        ON a.work_id = b.work_id AND a.current_version = b.version
    SET a.status_id = 2
    WHERE a.work_id NOT IN (
      SELECT ab.work_id
      FROM (SELECT s.work_id
            FROM work w INNER JOIN writer_split s
                ON w.work_id = s.work_id AND s.status_id != 2) ab
    );
  END;
```

when I run this create script, I am getting a syntax error.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

For me i will use `UPDATE work as a`

Comment: Thanks - as I've tried this is seems to keep crashing my SequelPRO client (macOS) and occasionally crashes the app that connects to the db. Any thoughts?